# How to pull javascript data into a form input field

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to create a gym membership database and it needs to store pictures taken with the webcam of the customer. I have the cam working and once you take the picture you can use the below code to 'echo' the url of the file.

The below code loads a URL:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getSnap(linky){
    alert(linky);
}
</script>
```

My question is how can I get it so the above code is automatically populated into a text field?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to select the input field by either id or class and set the value to the returned URL. In the below case, we use ID, so it would be whatever is the ID tag of the input is.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getSnap(linky){
    var elem = document.getElementById("myInput");
    elem.value = linky;
}
</script>

<input id="myInput" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a input called `#example`, you then place this instead of the alert

```
var example = document.getElementById('example');
example.value = linky; // set the value of an input
example.src = linky; // set the source of an image
example.innerHTML = linky; // Set as content of a div/block-element
example.href= linky; // set target for a anchor
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your text field an ID (ex URL) and use `document.getElementById('URL').value = linky;`